# React route - logout cannot redirect to correct page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I click Logout in the side menu,
It should return to /login, but still remain in the same route /home with content disappearing.

Explanation of a few states in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

import Login from "./Login";
import Drawer from "./Drawer";

console.warn = console.error = () => {};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isAuthenticating: true,
    user: null
  };

  setAuthStatus = (authenticated) => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: authenticated });
  };

  setUser = (user) => {
    this.setState({ user: user });
  };

  handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      //Sign Out api runs here
      this.setAuthStatus(false);
      this.setUser(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      // run api change to auth setAuthStatus
      // if api no return error > continue
      this.setAuthStatus(true);
      let user = { id: 123 };
      this.setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
  }

  render() {
    const authProps = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      user: this.state.user,
      setAuthStatus: this.setAuthStatus,
      setUser: this.setUser
    };
    return (
      !this.state.isAuthenticating && (
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
            <Drawer
              props={this.props}
              auth={authProps}
              handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
            />
          ) : (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from="/" to="/Login" />
                <Route
                  path="/login"
                  render={(props) => <Login {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
              </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

isAuthenticating:
 componentDidMount will call api to see if the session continues, 
if yes, isAuthenticating equals to true and it can prevent losing user auth in current session when refreshing the page or go to other route.

isAuthenticated: 
If !isAuthenticated > must stay in/redirect to Login Page

SandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-breeze-p5uih?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I works as expected in the sandbox. You hide the drawer and the main content if the user is logged out with the

```
this.state.isAuthenticated ? (Drawer) : <Login/>
```

You should seperate the drawer from your main content and merge the routers together. You should only use one router for the app in general. Also remove the redirect:

```
 <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
            <Drawer
              props={this.props}
              auth={authProps}
              handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
            />
          ) : (
            <BrowserRouter>
            <main
          className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open
          })}
        >
              <Switch>
              {Routes.map((route) => {
              return (
                <Route
                  path={route.path}
                  render={(prop) => (
                    <route.component {...prop} auth={props.auth} />
                  )}
                />
              );
            })}
                <Route
                  path="/login"
                  render={(props) => <Login {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
              </Switch>
              </main>
            </BrowserRouter>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
```

To route to the logout, first move the browser router up to index to wrap .
This will let you use the withRouter HigherOrderComponent:
`export default withRouter(App)`
Now you can access history from the props and move to login:

```
    this.props.history.push("/login")`
```

Comment: If I do in this way and remove the router in Drawer.js. It cannot work as expected

Comment: The workflow of my first:
npm start > first arrive /login > click logout will go back to /login

Comment: What is the use of <main> in your code?and should I need to remove the code about Router in  Drawer.js?

Comment: Also, regarding of your suggestions of removing <Redirect>, i use it because i want to browse the /login at the first time

Comment: I just copied the main from your code, since that was what you rendered in your routes. Why not trigger the redirect on mount?